# Firefox Addon to override system name resolution for certain host names?

Tags: dns, firefox

Is there any Firefox plugin that allows to change how Firefox perform name resolution? I want to override the system-wide hostname resolver to attach some IP to certain hostnames.

Let me explain. Let's say I'm developing a new website and I want to test using the actual hostname but my site is run by a local webserver, I'd like to do this:

```
System-wide resolver: www.domain.com ---> 10.20.30.40
Ovveride by addon:    www.domain.com ---> 127.0.0.1
```

Is there anything like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need a plugin to do that.  You can do it with the proxy settings.  Specifically, you can use the proxy auto-configuration option with a PAC file that you create.  The PAC file is written in javascript.  For you it might look something like this:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (host=='www.domain.com'){
        return 'PROXY 127.0.0.1:80';
    }
    // All other domains should connect directly without a proxy
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

Save this as my-proxy.pac file and point the proxy auto-configuration at it.

For more information on proxy autoconfiguration, see wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

Comment: Except this won't work for HTTPS.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493978/https-in-pac-file

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this answer won't help if the "old" server (or whatever machine you want to test without making it public) is on `localhost`, it is a generic solution that will work with remote sites and it supports HTTPS. You could do this on a private LAN.

You need SSH access to the server to test, and it must believe the domain(s) in question resolve to its own address. By "believe" I mean that machine has an entry in its `hosts` file for the relevant domains, or it has its own local DNS service with the desired `A` records (like cPanel servers do).

Create a [PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file with contents like the following:

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    var testingHost = 'domain-to-test.example';
    if (
        host === testingHost
        || dnsDomainIs(host, '.' + testingHost)
    ) {
        return 'SOCKS 127.1.1.1:1080';
    }
    return 'DIRECT';
}
```

In a terminal, create an SSH connection to the server with a SOCKS proxy like this:

```sh
ssh -N -D 127.1.1.1:1080 ADDRESS_OF_OLD_SERVER
```

where `ADDRESS_OF_OLD_SERVER` is replaced with the actual host or IP of the server to test.

In Firefox, you can now edit the proxy settings.
Select *Automatic proxy configuration URL* and enter the path to the file, e.g. `/home/yourname/my.pac`.
Tick the box for *Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5*, then click OK.

Now your DNS requests for that domain, and subsequent visits to it, should go through the SSH proxy to the "old" machine, where it will think "yes I'm that site" and serve you its own version.

When you're finished, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal to stop the SSH command, then put Firefox's proxy settings back to normal (usually *Use system proxy settings*).

Answer (score -1):

There are many Firefox add-ons that do just this:

- HostAdmin
- ChangeHosts
- SwitchHosts

A search for "Firefox hosts add-on" will yield a whole lot more.